# React-router-dom, Switch being replaced by Routes

Tags: reactjs, routes

I running into issues with the React-router-dom. Switch is now replaced by Routes. However, I'm getting a blank screen in the browser. No errors, just a blank screen. An explanation will be very appreciated.

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom';
import { Routes ,Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <Router>
      <Navbar/>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' exact />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
   </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Navbar.js

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

function Navbar() {
    return (
        <>
            <nav className='navbar'>
                <div className="navbar-container">
                <Link to='/' className='navbar-logo'>
                    React Website <i className='fab fa-typo3'/>
                </Link>
                <div className="menu-icon">
                    
                </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </>
    )
}

export default Navbar
```

Comment: Welcome. Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add tags. See [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score -1):

In `react-router-dom` v6 you must pass a component to each `<Route />` element in its element property.

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<App />}>
        <Route index element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="teams" element={<Teams />}>
          <Route path=":teamId" element={<Team />} />
          <Route path="new" element={<NewTeamForm />} />
          <Route index element={<LeagueStandings />} />
        </Route>
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
```